# How Can I working with WHERE and ORDER BY in my phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

Hello I am trying to where and order by together in mysql

this is my SQL QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM `lead_data` WHERE qa_status ='Pending' OR ORDER BY id DESC
```

Error :

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: You cannot OR ORDER BY what was your intention here.

Comment: Remove the OR for ORDER BY

Comment: Remove the `OR`

Answer (score 0):

Should be like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `lead_data` WHERE qa_status ='Pending' ORDER BY id DESC
```